# people search show no up to date information

Tags: sharepoint-online, search-results, people-search

When i search for someone on the search page of sharepoint i find the user but his informations are not up to date.
i check the profile on the sharepoint command center and exchange and everything is ok. Just the display on search wich is broken.

For exemple the departement is not up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like the people search index hasn't been updated for awhile, and since you are on SharePoint online there is no way to trigger a full crawl.

There are two options: a support ticket with MS, or try to 'force' a kinda full crawl by using Mikael Svenssons script : https://www.techmikael.com/2014/12/how-to-trigger-re-indexing-of-user.html